# Entity framework, changes not saved

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I'm encountering a problem that I've never seen. Everything worked perfectly before and from today my code doesn't save some updates.

My code is in t_inscription.cs

```
public void emailsent(t_inscriptions inscription = null)
{
    if (inscription == null)
    {
        inscription = this;
    }

    inscription.id_etat_inscription = 5;
    db.AcceptAllChanges();
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I debug , the app goes through this code, the object inscription is not null and correctly loaded, its id_etat_inscription turns to 5, and I receive no error message.

But then when I go to my db, I don't have no inscription with this id_etat_inscription at 5.

Note that it's a foreign key linked with a table "t_etats_inscriptions" containing ids froms 1 to 6.

Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot=)

Comment: Is the `inscription` object loaded through that `db` object?

Comment: have you created db object ?? or a transcation ??

Comment: Check the connection string to see if you use the correct DB

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
db.Entry<t_inscriptions >(inscription ).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

or

```
db.Entry(t_inscriptions).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I've tried with

db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(inscription, EntityState.Modified); but it says 

The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.t_inscriptions_7B7AED742874F1E74B514E55EEECC8C05213A5ED63B2C663B170C554262C4252'

So i thought I had to attach the object with db.t_inscriptions.Attach(inscription); but it seams like the "inscirption" object is already attached to another context (i don't understand this concept of contexts)

Comment: And when I try your code, it says that my db. does not contain a definition for Entry

Comment: If your entity is already attached to some other context that means some other method from where you pass this `t_inscription` object to the `emailsent` method is holding the reference. Can you show the method from where this method is called?

Comment: The method that calls this one only access values from inscription.

And the problem must come froim this because in my method when i do

        public void emailsent(t_inscriptions inscription = null)
        {if (inscription == null)
            {inscription = this;
            } t_inscriptions inscription2 = db.t_inscriptions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == inscription.id);
            inscription2.id_etat_inscription = 5;
            inscription.id_etat_inscription = 5;
           db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(inscription2, EntityState.Modified);db.SaveChanges();
        }it works

Answer (score 0):

I'll put it here cause it's "a solution to the problem",

When I replace my code by

```
public void emailsent(t_inscriptions inscription = null)
{
    if (inscription == null)
    {
        inscription = this;
    }

    t_inscriptions inscription2 = db.t_inscriptions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == inscription.id);
    inscription2.id_etat_inscription = 5;

    inscription.id_etat_inscription = 5;
   //db.Entry<t_inscriptions>(inscription).State = EntityState.Modified;
 //   db.t_inscriptions.Attach(inscription);
   db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(inscription2, EntityState.Modified);
  //  db.AcceptAllChanges();
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

It works :/